# Retriving data from a table in HTML by using nextSibling

Tags: javascript

I have two tables in HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td width="319" align="right" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" class="txtdarkgreybold">Article title:</td>
    <td width="346" align="left" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">My title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="txtdarkgreybold">Author:</td>
    <td align="left"><a href="/index.php?action=search&amp;name1=Przylipiak Mirosław&amp;results=10">Doe John</a><br /></td>
</tr>
```

By using `document.getElementsByClassName("txtdarkgreybold")` I can retrieve string `Article title:` but I am interested in what comes after it, that is: `My title`. How do I do this? In the second table I can get `Author:` but I am interested in `Doe John`. I was thinking about `nextSibling` as a way to get the strings that come after string I can get but I cannot implement it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)** with **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** :

```
document.querySelector('.txtdarkgreybold').nextElementSibling.textContent
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log( document.querySelectorAll('.txtdarkgreybold')[0].nextElementSibling.textContent );

console.log( document.querySelectorAll('.txtdarkgreybold')[1].nextElementSibling.textContent );
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="319" align="right" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" class="txtdarkgreybold">Article title:</td>
    <td width="346" align="left" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">My title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="txtdarkgreybold">Author:</td>
    <td align="left"><a href="/index.php?action=search&amp;name1=Przylipiak Mirosław&amp;results=10">Doe John</a><br /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works as supposed! Many thanks. I have one question thought: if this table is below other tables, how should I change your code to make it work? `document.querySelector(".txtdarkgreybold")[1].nextElementSibling.textContent` fails to work.

Comment: You've a nested table or just one after other?

Comment: I know too little to give you a good answer; however here's the page I want retrieve data from: http://www.archiwum.kino.org.pl/index.php?action=article_show&id=9757 . I translated strings into English: `Article title:` = `Tytuł artykułu : ` ; `Author:` = `Autor artykułu: `